# How to reduce the number of if

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to reduce the number of "if" in this code?

```
function test(input) {
  if ((input % 3 == 0) && (input % 5 == 0)) {
    return 'fizzbuzz';
  } else if (input % 3 == 0) {
    return 'fizz';
  } else if (input % 5 == 0) {
    return 'buzz';
  } else {
    return '' + input;
  }
}


for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  console.log(test(i));
}
```

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid that by storing the comparison values:

```
var mod3 = input % 3 == 0;
var mod5 = input % 5 == 0;
```

... creating a lookup table ...

```
var outs = [input, "fizz", "buzz", "fizzbuzz"];
```

... and indexing it ...

```
return outs[(+mod3) + 2 * (+mod5)];
```

... no `if`s!

Comment: Points for creativity, yet highly subject to breakage with when more conditions are added.

Comment: @ergonaut FizzBuzz is a *very* old challenge. I doubt it would really "change".

Comment: I've never heard of this, obviously it has never been promoted to Hello World status.

Comment: To make it less obscure, some named constants would do well: var MULTIPLE_OF_3=1, MULTIPLE_OF_5=2;

Comment: This has to be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
return ((input%3==0)&&(input%5==0)) ? 'fizz buzz'
       : (input%3==0) ? 'fizz'
       : (input%5==0) ? 'buzz'
       : '' + input;
```

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Technically it isn't an `if` at all, though it is an expression that can be substituted for an `if/else` statement. He didn't say he wanted to reduce the number of conditions, just the number of `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use if's why not try case syntax?

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Alternatively use the JS shorthand for if

so that:

```
var something;

if (2 + 2 === 4){
 something = "Yup!"
} else {
 something = "Nope"
}
```

becomes

```
var something = 2 + 2 === 4 ? "Yup!" : "Nope";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the first "if" altogether, because 3 and 5 and "fizz" and "buzz" are used in the later ones. You can also wait to return until the end. Something like:

```
var str = "";

if (input % 3 === 0){
  str +="fizz";
}

if (input % 5 === 0 ){
  str +="buzz";
} else {
str = input;
}

return str;
```

Comment: You're never going to get "fizz" alone. It'll always be "buzz", "fizzbuzz" or the `input`.